# Using cummean with group_by and ignoring NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(category=c("cat1","cat1","cat2","cat1","cat2","cat2","cat1","cat2"),
                 value=c(NA,2,3,4,5,NA,7,8))
```

I'd like to add a new column to the above dataframe which takes the cumulative mean of the `value` column, not taking into account NAs. Is it possible to do this with `dplyr`? I've tried

```
df <- df %>% group_by(category) %>% mutate(new_col=cummean(value))
```

but `cummean` just doesn't know what to do with NAs.

EDIT: I do not want to count NAs as 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `ifelse` to treat `NA`s as `0` for the `cummean` call:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(category=c("cat1","cat1","cat2","cat1","cat2","cat2","cat1","cat2"),
                 value=c(NA,2,3,4,5,NA,7,8))

df %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(new_col = cummean(ifelse(is.na(value), 0, value)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   category [2]
  category value new_col
  <fct>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 cat1       NA     0.  
2 cat1        2.    1.00
3 cat2        3.    3.00
4 cat1        4.    2.00
5 cat2        5.    4.00
6 cat2       NA     2.67
7 cat1        7.    3.25
8 cat2        8.    4.00
```

EDIT: Now I see this isn't the same as ignoring NAs.

Try this one instead. I group by a column which specifies if the value is `NA` or not, meaning `cummean` can run without encountering any NAs:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(category=c("cat1","cat1","cat2","cat1","cat2","cat2","cat1","cat2"),
                 value=c(NA,2,3,4,5,NA,7,8))

df %>%
  group_by(category, isna = is.na(value)) %>%
  mutate(new_col = ifelse(isna, NA, cummean(value)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   category, isna [4]
  category value isna  new_col
  <fct>    <dbl> <lgl>   <dbl>
1 cat1       NA  TRUE    NA   
2 cat1        2. FALSE    2.00
3 cat2        3. FALSE    3.00
4 cat1        4. FALSE    3.00
5 cat2        5. FALSE    4.00
6 cat2       NA  TRUE    NA   
7 cat1        7. FALSE    4.33
8 cat2        8. FALSE    5.33
```

Comment: In this method `NA` are not ignored during calculation of `mean`. Perhaps `OP` wants to ignore `NA` values while calculating mean.

Comment: Thanks! I realised I also need this to be able to calculate the cumulative mean not including the current observation - unfortunately using `ifelse(isna, NA, cummean(lag(value)))` doesn't work as `lag` generates NAs. I have posted it as a seperate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49909523/cumulative-mean-non-including-the-current-observation-using-cummean-and-group

Answer (score 1):

An option is to remove value before calculating `cummean`. In this method rows with `NA` value will not be accounted for `cummean` calculation. Not sure if OP wants to consider `NA` value as `0` in calculation.

```
df %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(new_col = cummean(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  right_join(mutate(df, rn = row_number()), by="rn") %>%
  select(category = category.y, value = value.y, new_col) %>%
  as.data.frame()
#    category value  new_col
# 1     cat1    NA       NA
# 2     cat1     2 2.000000
# 3     cat2     3 3.000000
# 4     cat1     4 3.000000
# 5     cat2     5 4.000000
# 6     cat2    NA       NA
# 7     cat1     7 4.333333
# 8     cat2     8 5.333333
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed something similar, but cannot replace `NAs` with `0`. So I created this simple function, which works with `dplyr`. Hope this helps.

```
cummean.na <- function(x, na.rm = T)
{
  # x = c(NA, seq(1, 10, 1)); na.rm = T
  n <- length(x)
  op <- rep(NA, n)
  for(i in 1:n) {op[i] <- ifelse(is.na(x[i]), NA, mean(x[1:i], na.rm = !!na.rm))}
  rm(x, na.rm, n, i)
  return(op)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom function to calculate "cummean", ignoring `NA`'s and carrying forward the previous cumulative mean value to the next `NA` value:

```
cummean.na <-
    function(x) {
        
        tmp_ind <- cumsum(!is.na(x))
        
        x_nona <- x[!is.na(x)]
        
        out <- cummean(x_nona)[tmp_ind]
        
        return(out)
        
    }
```

Example output:

```
> cummean.na(1:5)
[1] 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0
> cummean.na(c(1, 2, 3, NA, 4, 5))
[1] 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.0 2.5 3.0
```