# Cumulative mean non including the current observation - using cummean and group_by while ignoring NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(category=c("cat1","cat1","cat2","cat1","cat2","cat2","cat1","cat2"),
                 value=c(NA,2,3,4,5,NA,7,8))
```

I'd like to add a new column to the above dataframe which takes the cumulative mean of the `value` column up to the prior observation (ie not including the current observation) and not taking into account NAs. I've tried

```
df %>%
  group_by(category, isna = is.na(value)) %>%
  mutate(new_col = ifelse(isna, NA, cummean(lag(value))))
```

but `cummean` just doesn't know what to do with NAs and unfortunately `lag` generates them.

I do not want to count NAs as 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can workout first `cummean` and then take `lag` of the same.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(category, isna = is.na(value)) %>%
  mutate(new_col = lag(cummean(value))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-isna)


# # A tibble: 8 x 3
# category value new_col
# <fctr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 cat1     NA      NA   
# 2 cat1      2.00   NA   
# 3 cat2      3.00   NA   
# 4 cat1      4.00    2.00
# 5 cat2      5.00    3.00
# 6 cat2     NA      NA   
# 7 cat1      7.00    3.00
# 8 cat2      8.00    4.00
```