# cumulative mean by group with NA in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I wanted to use `cummean` by groups ignoring `NA`. Here is the sample data.

```
data.frame(group1 = c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,3)),
           val = c(c(NA,4,5),c(NA,NA,5),c(1,NA,3)))
```

How can I get cumulative mean by group ignoring `NA`?

Here is my desired out

```
c(NA,4,4.5,NA,NA,5,1,1,2)
```

Comment: I don't think the duplicate link address the question OP asked

Comment: Here is more appropriate duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906503/using-cummean-with-group-by-and-ignoring-nas

Answer (score 2):

We can use `replace` to ignore the `NA` elements in calculating the `cummean`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(group1) %>%
     mutate(new = replace(val, !is.na(val), cummean(val[!is.na(val)]))) %>%
     fill(new)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   group1 [3]
#  group1   val   new
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1      1    NA  NA  
#2      1     4   4  
#3      1     5   4.5
#4      2    NA  NA  
#5      2    NA  NA  
#6      2     5   5  
#7      3     1   1  
#8      3    NA   1  
#9      3     3   2
```

Comment: I ignore NAs not treat those as zero. Can you take a look at the desired output?

Comment: @Johnlegend2 i think in the expected output, you showed `5 1 1 2` instead of `5 1 NA 2` because the 8th obs is NA in input

Comment: Thank you so much. How can I have desired output? can I have non-NA value 8th row?

Comment: @Johnlegend2 you can use `fill` updated the post